Spontaneous symmetry breaking - incorrect Peierl's argument in the continuous 3d $O(3)$ model
The following must be wrong but I don't see why:
Consider an $O(3)$ model in $d=2$ dimensions. Gapless Goldstone bosons (magnons) at $k\to 0$ are the lowest-energy excitations of the system with some infinitesimal energy $\epsilon(|k|)$ and are associated to the breaking of the $SO(3)$ symmetry.
Now, a Peierl's-like argument is employed. The change in free energy due to the magnon excitation is composed of the change in energy $\Delta E=\epsilon$ and the change of entropy $\Delta S$ associated with the number of such possible excitations at fixed energy. $\Delta S>0$ since the modes are degenerate due to $\epsilon(k) = \epsilon(|k|)$. This degeneracy is independent of $|k|$. One concludes that for all finite temperatures $T$ one can choose $k$ such that $$\Delta F = \Delta E - T\Delta S = \epsilon(|k|)-T\Delta S <0.$$
Following this logic, one finds that there is no spontaneous magnetization at finite temperature since averaging the spin over the long-wavelength magnon state yields 0. One would then also say that there cannot be spontaneous symmetry breaking at $T>0$. Thus there seems to be no phase transition between a magnetic ($m\neq0$) to a non-magnetic ($m=0$) phase. This is clearly incorrect. Why?

Sounds consistent with the Mermin Wagner theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem

But I am looking at a 3d system so I do not see how Mermin Wagner would apply

Didn't you say that it was in $d=2$ dimensions?

The Mermin Wagner theorem applies to spatial dimension, not the dimension of the internal symmetry group (in fact, the higher the dimension of the internal symmetry group, the faster you would expect the two-point correlation function to decay.)
